# Create a Talk/Discuss link in a MediaWiki Plug-in

Tags: mediawiki

I am creating a MediaWiki plug-in that lists many files. For each file, I want to print a [Talk] or [Discuss] link. (It seems that the original name was talk but that it was renamed to discuss.) These links should be red if the page does not exist and blue if it does exist.

There should be a way to add such links in OutputPage.php, but I can't figure it out.

I know about these functions "foo":

```
$page = WikiPage::factory ( $title )
$talk = $title->getTalkPage()
```

But I'm not sure how to get `$title` from `foo`.

I'm also not sure how to change `$talk` into the appropriate HTML. I'd rather not add it to the output stream, because I'm building a lot of HTML separately, but I suppose I can refactor so that instead of passing my strings around, I pass around a handle to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `OutputPage::addWikiText()` to add the appropriate link without worrying about the technical details: `[[{{ns:11}}:Foo|Text]]` for example.

Alternatively you can get `$title` from `OutputPage::getTitle()` for the current page, or from `Title::newFromText()` for any title you want to use. You can get `$talk` directly by specifying the correct namespace constant, which might be even easier than the trip via a WikiPage object.

Correct styling for the link can be done with the helper methods `Title::exists()` and one of the appropriate helpers for generating urls for pages.

See also https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classTitle.html

Comment: You can get the talk page via the Title object, WikiPage is not needed.

Comment: Yeah what I meant is that you can do something like `$talk = Title::newFromText('foo', NS_TALK);` and you directly get the talk page title, without getting the subject page `$title` first

Comment: That will break if `Foo` is not in the main namespace, though.

Comment: That's true, fair enough.

Comment: `OutputPage::addWikiText()` is precisely what I am looking for! Thanks. It would be great to find simple, concise, easy-to-read documentation for plug-in writers.